# Can someone please explain the proper usage of Timers and Triggers in Apache Beam?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, apache-beam, google-cloud-pubsub

I'm looking for some examples of usage of Triggers and Timers in Apache beam, I wanted to use Processing-time timers for listening my data from pub sub in every 5 minutes and using Processing time triggers processing the above data collected in an hour altogether in python.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please take a look at the following resources: [Stateful processing with Apache Beam](https://beam.apache.org/blog/stateful-processing/) and [Timely (and Stateful) Processing with Apache Beam](https://beam.apache.org/blog/timely-processing/)

The first blog post is more general in how to handle states for context, and the second has some examples on buffering and triggering after a certain period of time, which seems similar to what you are trying to do.

---

A full example was requested. Here is what I was able to come up with:

```java
    PCollection<String> records =
        pipeline.apply(
            "ReadPubsub",
            PubsubIO.readStrings()
                .fromSubscription(
                    "projects/{project}/subscriptions/{subscription}"));

    TupleTag<Iterable<String>> every5MinTag = new TupleTag<>();
    TupleTag<Iterable<String>> everyHourTag = new TupleTag<>();

    PCollectionTuple timersTuple =
        records
            .apply("WithKeys", WithKeys.of(1)) // A KV<> is required to use state. Keying by data is more appropriate than hardcode.
            .apply(
                "Batch",
                ParDo.of(
                        new DoFn<KV<Integer, String>, Iterable<String>>() {

                          @StateId("buffer5Min")
                          private final StateSpec<BagState<String>> bufferedEvents5Min =
                              StateSpecs.bag();

                          @StateId("count5Min")
                          private final StateSpec<ValueState<Integer>> countState5Min =
                              StateSpecs.value();

                          @TimerId("every5Min")
                          private final TimerSpec every5MinSpec =
                              TimerSpecs.timer(TimeDomain.PROCESSING_TIME);

                          @StateId("bufferHour")
                          private final StateSpec<BagState<String>> bufferedEventsHour =
                              StateSpecs.bag();

                          @StateId("countHour")
                          private final StateSpec<ValueState<Integer>> countStateHour =
                              StateSpecs.value();

                          @TimerId("everyHour")
                          private final TimerSpec everyHourSpec =
                              TimerSpecs.timer(TimeDomain.PROCESSING_TIME);

                          @ProcessElement
                          public void process(
                              @Element KV<Integer, String> record,
                              @StateId("count5Min") ValueState<Integer> count5MinState,
                              @StateId("countHour") ValueState<Integer> countHourState,
                              @StateId("buffer5Min") BagState<String> buffer5Min,
                              @StateId("bufferHour") BagState<String> bufferHour,
                              @TimerId("every5Min") Timer every5MinTimer,
                              @TimerId("everyHour") Timer everyHourTimer) {

                            if (Objects.firstNonNull(count5MinState.read(), 0) == 0) {
                              every5MinTimer
                                  .offset(Duration.standardMinutes(1))
                                  .align(Duration.standardMinutes(1))
                                  .setRelative();
                            }
                            buffer5Min.add(record.getValue());

                            if (Objects.firstNonNull(countHourState.read(), 0) == 0) {
                              everyHourTimer
                                  .offset(Duration.standardMinutes(60))
                                  .align(Duration.standardMinutes(60))
                                  .setRelative();
                            }
                            bufferHour.add(record.getValue());
                          }

                          @OnTimer("every5Min")
                          public void onTimerEvery5Min(
                              OnTimerContext context,
                              @StateId("buffer5Min") BagState<String> bufferState,
                              @StateId("count5Min") ValueState<Integer> countState) {
                            if (!bufferState.isEmpty().read()) {
                              context.output(every5MinTag, bufferState.read());
                              bufferState.clear();
                              countState.clear();
                            }
                          }

                          @OnTimer("everyHour")
                          public void onTimerEveryHour(
                              OnTimerContext context,
                              @StateId("bufferHour") BagState<String> bufferState,
                              @StateId("countHour") ValueState<Integer> countState) {
                            if (!bufferState.isEmpty().read()) {
                              context.output(everyHourTag, bufferState.read());
                              bufferState.clear();
                              countState.clear();
                            }
                          }
                        })
                    .withOutputTags(every5MinTag, TupleTagList.of(everyHourTag)));

    timersTuple
        .get(every5MinTag)
        .setCoder(IterableCoder.of(StringUtf8Coder.of()))
        .apply(<<do something every 5 min>>);
    timersTuple
        .get(everyHourTag)
        .setCoder(IterableCoder.of(StringUtf8Coder.of()))
        .apply(<< do something every hour>>);

    pipeline.run().waitUntilFinish();
```

Comment: I've had a look but am confused in implementing it and the use of it, maybe an example of a specific use case would help alot!

Comment: Added an example, please check if it's useful.

Comment: Eh, missed the hint that it was in Python. I am still getting used to the Python SDK -- but the same concepts apply. Let me know if you have any issue converting the pipeline above.

Comment: Actually I'm totally new to Beam and JAVA aswell but am well versed with python, so for sure would be a great help but this itself was a great help!!!